# Fastest way to do PCA in MATLAB for very high dimensional data (princomp too slow)

Tags: matlab, statistics, linear-algebra

I am trying to find the principal components of very high dimensional data (~20,000). The `princomp` function that comes with MATLAB takes way too long (~10 seconds) to compute. I was wondering if there are faster ways to do this. I have been looking for `mex` implementations of this algorithm with no luck so far.

Thanks

Comment: do you need ALL of them?

Comment: @natan I would like to use at least the first few principal components..

Comment: @MinLin I shall take a look at lanpack.. but the data I have may not be sparse.. will that be an issue? Thanks

Comment: When the rank of the matrix is low, it would be quite efficient, but when it is not, I think it will be slower without losing accuracy, but I'm not 100 percent sure.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use just the instructions that you want to calculate PCA, for example:

```
[V E] = eig(cov(X));
[E S] = sort(diag(E),'descend');
V = V(:,S);
```

Comment: Using `[V E] = eig(cov(X));` takes just as long.

Comment: @MinLin: Can you support your statement with any reference or simulation?